# images form document

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage

i have an image in document folder. i want show it in table view.
i try but what is wrong i don't know my code is

```
NSString *imagelist = some image name.png;  

//-----------
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagelist];


UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,50,40)];
 // img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];
[cell.contentView addSubview:img];


NSURL *pptURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourFilePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pptURL];
[img loadRequest:request];
[cell.contentView addSubview:img];
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Sample code to parse, create uitableview and create a iphone app is available. You just need to google, put together the pieces and create the app. You may not get people who will write the code for you here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the developer docs from Apple?
There is a guide to XML programming with sample code and everything you need to know.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186-SW1

Comment: sorry, I have no time to write your code. Probably you have some difficulties with the language, but believe me, the official Apple docs are enough. There is also plenty of example code. I did it last week, without prior knowledge about XML parsing with Cocoa.